# how to jpa share Sring key?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

DB schema

```
|Order   |   |Delivery|
==========   ==========
|order_id|   |order_id| (order_id is PK)
             |address |
```

Object

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Order {

  /* shout not exist Delivery reference*/
  
  @Id
  @Column(name = "order_id")
  private String id;

}


@Entity
@Data
public class Delivery {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @MapsId
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
  private Order order;

  private String name;
}
```

and db insert

```java
@Test
void insert(){
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    orderRepository.save(order);

    Delivery delivery = new Delivery();
    delivery.setOrder(order);
    deliveryRepository.save(delivery);
}
```

error message:
SQL Error: 42001, SQLState: 42001
Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ORDER0_.ORDER_ID AS ORDER_ID1_2_0_ FROM ORDER[*] ORDER0_ WHERE ORDER0_.ORDER_ID=?"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:

I tried various things, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you post your complete error log and format it.

Comment: just by the way, it's never a good idea to use reserved words to name tables or columns, in your case `order`

Answer (score 0):

`Order` is a keyword in most databases. So either you quote the name, or you activate auto-quoting in Hibernate. Also see the documentation for a reference about this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers